# Indy UDP communication

Tags: c++, udp, indy10, rad

I want to develop a program in RAD Studio C++ to communicate with some microcontroller boards over an Ethernet LAN.

I found Indy `TIdUDPClient`, and I can communicate with only one microcontroller board, eg:

```
My PC IP:192.168.10.100
MCU Board 1 IP: 192.168.10.1
MCU Board 2 IP: 192.168.10.2 
MCU Board 3 IP: 192.168.10.3
```

Only one MCU board answers.  I want to communicate with all of them (maybe broadcast?).

I cannot find information about how to change Indy's `TIdUDPClient` Host IP address during runtime.

Can anyone advise me how to do this?

Comment: Which "Host IP" do you want to change exactly?  The local IP that `TIdUDPClient` binds to for receiving packets (use the `BoundIP` property), or the remote IP that it sends packets to (use the `Host` property).

Comment: Hi, Remy I want to communicate first between My PC(192.168.10.100) <-> and MCU1 (192.168.10.1) and after second My PC(192.168.10.100) <-> and MCU2 (192.168.10.2) and after third My PC(192.168.10.100) <-> and MCU3 (192.168.10.3) and than first again in cyclic program. All MCU board get different data in UDP packet.

Comment: so, what is stopping you from being able to accomplish this exactly? Please [edit] your question to show the actual code you are having trouble with. You can bind `TIdUDPClient` to 192.168.10.100, then send packets to each MCU IP as needed. When reading a packet back, it can tell you which MCU sent it